# Cloned list being altered when the original list is being altered

Tags: python, list

Here is the code:

```
def Class(clas12):
inputData = ''.join(clas12.readlines())
line=inputData.split('\n')
line2=[]
for a in line:
    b=a.split(' ')
    line2.append(b)
return line2

clas12=open('class12.txt','r')

Class12=Class(clas12)
Class13=list(Class12)
```

When I alter Class12( such by .remove, .append), the same change will be applied to Class13. This is frustrating because I need the original list for another function. Is there a way to keep the original list or copy it so that it won't be altered?

Comment: Google `deep cloning` vs `shallow cloning`. What you are doing is called `shallow copying`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default python uses references rather than copies, it is faster an more memory efficient that way - if you need a copy that you can alter without changing the original:

```
import copy

def Class(clas12):
inputData = ''.join(clas12.readlines())
line=inputData.split('\n')
line2=[]
for a in line:
    b=a.split(' ')
    line2.append(b)
return line2

clas12=open('class12.txt','r')

Class12=Class(clas12)
Class13=copy.deepcopy(Class12)
```